# Formatting data from a combo box linked to a query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I built a combo box using a query with the aim to extract a list of contacts from a contact list. Unfortunately, what is returned are the unique ID numbers of each contact instead of the text of their names.

Comment: Check your column assignments.  If the query itself contains the 'name', then it is in the combo box as long as 'columns' is sufficient and the column width property is not zero for that field.

Comment: Wayne, i dont understand but it is not working. I have queried both the name and the numerical ID. I have also ensured there are two columns present in the properties.  It is returning two sets of number.

Comment: Run your query by itself and see if you get the 'name'.

Comment: Wayne, im not sure exactly what you mean but I have created a query on my own with the tables and fields and it returns the correct values.

Comment: Can you be more specific about 'It is returning two sets of numbers'? Are you saying your combobox has two columns but they are both numbers but one should be a name? Or are you saying you are running a report or have a form that shows two sets of numbers and one should be a name? In your original question, most people would assume you mean your combobox is returning numbers instead of names. If that is the case, you need to run your SQL manually to determine if that is the cause of the problem. If not, then you need to look at the box definition and column references.

Comment: SELECT tblProjectGovernanceResources.[ID Resource], tblProjectGovernanceResources.Contact FROM tblProjectGovernanceResources INNER JOIN tblHoldingProjectID ON tblProjectGovernanceResources.[ID Project] = tblHoldingProjectID.ID_Project GROUP BY tblProjectGovernanceResources.[ID Resource], tblProjectGovernanceResources.Contact ORDER BY tblProjectGovernanceResources.Contact;

Comment: The above query specifically requests the Contact field which is text.

Comment: If you are saying you ran that query manually and it returns numbers in the 'Contact' field, then I suggest you open the table 'tblProjectGovernanceResources' sort on the 'Contact' field and look at the data. Do you see numbers? If so, but they are not supposed to be there, your data has been compromised.

Answer (score 0):

Comboboxes can have more than one column, by default it has only one column. if you assign ID;Names you also need to set the column number to 2 otherwise combobox will never know /show the second column (names).

in your design environment,

1. Select your combobox
2. select the format section in the property sheet.
3. set the [column count] value to 2 (as per how many columns your query has)
4. set the [Column widths] value to 0 (to hide the first column [ID] width, for more columns use 0;secondcolWidth;ThirdcolWidth)

this should fix your problem.

**EDIT:**
by default combobox default value is bound to column 0, you can change that by changing the property [bound column] property in the property sheet (Data tab)

Comment: Gentlemen, I have tried almost everything but it is not working. When i create the combo box i go to the data source screen and build the query. Viewing the query the list of names shows exactly as i would like to see them from the drop down menu. On the format tab i make sure the column count is 2 and the width to the first is set to zero.  My query is as follows: SELECT tblProjectGovernanceResources.Contact FROM tblProjectGovernanceResources INNER JOIN tblHoldingProjectID ON tblProjectGovernanceResources.[ID Project] = tblHoldingProjectID.ID_Project;

Comment: Also, i built a query from scratch using the source table and the names showed correctly. Upon building the combo box using the query, the same problem exists. Is it possible that the original source table where the user enters the name is setup incorrectly?

Comment: your query should have two columns,SELECT tblProjectGovernanceResources.Contact_id,tblProjectGovernanceResources.Contact from ...